# Can I put my profile flair in my emails?

Tags: discussion, flair

Stackoverflow flair can be used on html pages, is there a way that I can use that html code to put that flair at the bottom of my emails ?

Comment: Download the flair image and embed in your email. Or in HTML email, you can embed it directly - can't guarantee that will work though.

Comment: Depends... If you're writing a program to do it, go search on Stack Overflow as there are plenty of answers there. Otherwise, it completely depends on what you use for emailing.

Comment: It really depends on the email client, some block external images and/or HTML. Nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Please stop sending HTML e-mails, thank you. Alternatively, please stop sending *pure* HTML e-mails without a text version, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy paste the flair image into the mail. That should work (it works in GMail). Note that some email providers swap out the image with an embedded one. Some email clients also disallow by default external images and HTML elements in e-mails, and some users just view their e-mails as plain text.

Comment: Also note that some e-mail clients do not load external images by default...also note that some people view e-mails as plaintext (and having to parse *manually* through HTML because there is no text version provided is not fun).